# Hidden top menu in Eclipse with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem with Eclipse. After a computer reboot the top menu has disappeared, and I don't know why. Now Eclipse looks like this :

[image]

Next to the minimize and exit buttons should be the menu, but it is not.

Comment: Well I'm shooting into the blue here, but try to open a terminal and type in `unity` after the desktop restored itself reopen eclipse and see if the menus are there.